# CONFIGURATION OF MOBILE WIFI HOTSPOT IN ELEMENTARY OS 6 ODIN DESKTOP

Tags: wifi

I'm using Elementary OS 6 as guest through Oracle VM VirtualBox in host Ubuntu 20.04 desktop. I would like to configure Mobile Hotspot in the Elementary through WIFI Adapter. This is possible in Ubuntu & Windows too. It may be possible in Elementary but due to my ignorance. However, I couldn't find any wifi button in Network Page of Elementary. There are only 3 buttons viz. Wired, VPN, Proxy. Need advise from community members.

Comment: VirtualBox will present the host hardware using generic devices, which means Ethernet for networks. You will need to use a hardware pass-through for the wifi device if you want Elementary to see it as a wifi device 

Comment: @matigo Do you mean that I should initiate mobile wifi hotspot first in host i.e. Ubuntu?